# Update bootstrap Table when Click Edit Button in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Here. I have codeigniter update code, it also worked but the problem is when i click the Edit button did not parsing After space data.
**(After space Words did not fetch in update model).**
How can I solve this problem.

**vvIncome.php view**

```js
$(document).on('click','.btn_edit', function(e) {
  $("#edit").val($(this).attr('edit_id'));
  $("#in_dis").val($(this).attr("in_dis"));
  $("#in_amnt").val($(this).attr('in_amnt'));
  $("#confirm-edit").modal({show:'true'});
      
});
   
$(document).on('click', '#btn-ys', function() {   
var income_id = $('#edit').val();
var in_dis = $('#in_dis').val();  
var in_amnt = $('#in_amnt').val();
var result{"income_id":income_id,"in_dis":in_dis,"in_amnt":in_amnt};
       
 $.ajax({
data:result,
type: "POST",
url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/income/editincome/'+income_id,
success: function(data){    
$("#confirm-edit").modal('hide');
viewData();
     }
 });
});
```

**View PHP Code**

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-md" id="confirm-edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">EDIT CATEGORY</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="well">
<form class="form-horizontal">

<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <input type="text"class="form-control" id="in_dis" placeholder="description">
</div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="in_amnt" placeholder="amount">
 </div>
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <input type="hidden" class="form-control"     id="edit" placeholder="income_id">
</div>
 </div>

 <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
 <button type="button" id="btn-ys" class="btn btn-success">SUBMIT</button>
 </div>
 </form>
    </div>
</div>         
    </div>
 </div>
```

`
**Income_resut.php**

```html
<thead>
<tr>
<th ><center>DESCRIPTION</center></th>
<th ><center>AMOUNT</center></th>
<th ><center>EDIT</center></th>
<th ><center>DELETE</center></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php foreach ($incm as $in_key) { ?>
 <tr>
<td><center><?php echo $in_key->description;?></center></td>
<td><center><?php echo $in_key->amount;?></center></td>
<td>
<center><button type="button" title="edit" data-toggle="modal" edit_id=<?php echo $in_key->income_id;?> in_dis=<?php echo $in_key->description;?> in_amnt=<?php echo $in_key->amount;?>  class="btn btn-info btn_edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></center>
</td>
<td>
<center><button type="button" title="delete" data-toggle="modal" del_id=<?php echo $in_key->income_id;?> class="btn btn-danger btn-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></center>
</td>
<?php } ?>
 </table>
```

`

**income.php Controller**

```html
public function editincome($income_id)
{
$udata['income_id'] = $this->input->POST('income_id'); 
$udata['description'] = $this->input->POST('in_dis');
$udata['amount'] = $this->input->POST('in_amnt');
$update = $this->income_model>update_income_details($udata,$income_id);
 }
```

**Income_Model.php** Model

```html
public function update_income_details($udata,$income_id)
 {
 $this->db->from('income', $udata);
 $this->db->where('income_id',$income_id );
 return $this->db->update('income',$udata);
 }
```

**This on view table** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIFbP.jpg)

**This is edit model**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtuGU.jpg)

Comment: Can you please provide some details regarding `After space character cannot view in update model` ? I didn't understood your question.

Comment: when i click  the edit button did not fetch after space letters  from view table. example-> description- "My name is Robin" but when i click update  "My" letter only fetched.

Comment: Could you show a sample html code for '.btn_edit'?

Comment: yes i post on this question check (boostrap model) vvIncome.php view

Comment: No, I can only see the jquery code for '.btn_edit' not the HTML. Could you show some sample?

Comment: Thanks but I still need to see a sample 'html code' for the 'edit button' in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIFbP.jpg

Comment: I would advise you to use `data-in_dis="This is a description"` and get the value by using `$(this).data('in_dis');`

Comment: $(this).data('in_dis'); I didn't understand can u enplane clearly.

Comment: Income_resut.php @rAjA now just i post the edit_btn php code any help

Comment: @RobinHood let me know if the answer I posted works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to this,

for eg, `in_dis=<?php echo $in_key->description;?>` to `data-in_dis="<?php echo rawurlencode($in_key->description); ?>"`

then 
`$("#in_dis").val($(this).attr("in_dis"));` to `$("#in_dis").val(decodeURIComponent($(this).data("in_dis")));`

*Use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`*

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank You So much , Yes It's Working  <3